# fragment don't want to refresh ListView

Tags: android, android-fragments

i've got a little problem here: i have fragment with ListView, calling onResume have to get list for that ListView. everything is fine, but list shows only if you switch to another fragment and switch back. what is wrong with it? 
onResume method

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("searchFragment", "called onResume");

    if (serviceInfo.getPlayList()!=null){
        list=serviceInfo.getPlayList();
        Log.i("searchFragment", "called onResume, called listSetter");
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

[sources](https://github.com/Nickdnepr/diplomProject)

Comment: i think getPlayList returns empty list at first run. Can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when the time ur fragment created and onResume, the method you called which is **serviceInfo.getPlayList()** still null

Maybe you can post your code here, so that i can help you to check, cheers

Comment: The list didnt shown up after you clicked on the button to pull data from server?

Comment: no, list didnt shown after the pulling data from serviceInfo class after activity restart